# Can the specific heat capacity be time dependent, but not temperature dependent?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Can the specific heat capacity be time dependent, but not temperature dependent in a close system that does not have a heat source/sink term?

Comment: As a chemical reaction is occurring or a phase transition.

Comment: Consider a porous body in which the pores are gradually drained or filled with water.
Strictly speaking this is not a close system, but such bodies still need to be analysed.

Comment: yes, of course it can be. In your example you have two bodies in contact, one has capacity $xC_1$, the other $(1-x)C_2$ and $0\le x=x(t) \le 1$ a prescribed time function and these two bodies are in thermal contact so the total heat cap is the sum $xC_1+(1-x)C_2$ but with spatially variable thermal conductivities $k_1$ and $k_2$ and also similar time dependent spatial extent; a very nasty problem. The phase transition @Farcher is referring to is one example, check out the so-called Stefan's problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan_problem.